# CCLabelTTF invisible issue in iOS 7.0

Tags: ipad, ios7, cocos2d-x, cclabelttf

I'm using cocos2d-x 2.0.4 for my game. 
CCLabelTTF works well on both of device and simulator in iOS 6. But when i test it in iOS 7.0, it doesn't work. 
Here is my code.

```
    int nScore = 10;
    char str[50];
    sprintf(str, "SCORE : %d", nScore);
    CCLabelTTF *lbl = CCLabelTTF::create(str, "Marker Felt", 50);
    lbl->setPosition(ccp(size.width*0.5, size.height*0.88));
    lbl->setColor(ccRED);
    this->addChild(lbl);
```

Score doesn't show now. But it shows in iOS 6.
One more strange problem.
If i change above code like this, it works.

```
    CCLabelTTF *lbl = CCLabelTTF::create("SCORE", "Marker Felt", 50);
    lbl->setPosition(ccp(size.width*0.5, size.height*0.88));
    lbl->setColor(ccRED);
    this->addChild(lbl);
```

But if i change this code like below again, it doesn't work.(invisible)

```
    CCLabelTTF *lbl = CCLabelTTF::create("Score", "Marker Felt", 50);
    lbl->setPosition(ccp(size.width*0.5, size.height*0.88));
    lbl->setColor(ccRED);
    this->addChild(lbl);
```

Maybe it's case sensitive issue.

Finally below code doesn't work too even if text is upper case. I only added number 10.

```
    CCLabelTTF *lbl = CCLabelTTF::create("SCORE : 10", "Marker Felt", 50);
    lbl->setPosition(ccp(size.width*0.5, size.height*0.88));
    lbl->setColor(ccRED);
    this->addChild(lbl);
```

Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible cause: the `str` variable is created on the stack and becomes a dangling pointer once the method returns. Unless CCLabelTTF copies the string.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem while using cocos2d-x 2.1.3. I found [this](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/141) link stating that the issue is a bug that affects labels in iOS 7. In order to fix the issue, you'll need to either update the engine, or merge [this](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/2873) pull request manually.

Comment: I've tried to update cocos2d-x engine, but when i did it, there were some errors. Could you please let me know how to update engine or merge the pull request manually?

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your cocos2d-x version it fixed in 3.0 and if you are using cocos2dx older version then change into **CCimage.mm** this statment

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data,dim.width,dim.height, 8,dim.width * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, (size_t)dim.width, (size_t)dim.height, 8, (size_t)dim.width * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
```